# Python Ultralytics YOLOv5 | index: 2 Got: 384 Expected: 640

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo, onnx, yolov5

#### Question

I have been using the Ultralytics Python module to use my yolov5 model made with Ultralytics Hub
I switched to doing it this way, (gives more customization):
https://docs.ultralytics.com/yolov5/tutorials/train_custom_data

However if I try to use the Ultralytics module to load the model, I get this:

```
TypeError: ERROR  best.pt appears to be an Ultralytics YOLOv5 model originally trained with https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5.
This model is NOT forwards compatible with YOLOv8 at https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics.
Recommend fixes are to train a new model using the latest 'ultralytics' package or to run a command with an official YOLOv8 model, i.e. 'yolo predict model=yolov8n.pt'
```

So I switched to using torch.hub.load()
It loads the model fine, however when it trys to get detection results, I get this error:

```
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.InvalidArgument: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 2 : INVALID_ARGUMENT : Got invalid dimensions for input: images for the following indices
 index: 2 Got: 384 Expected: 640
 Please fix either the inputs or the model.
```

I have gotten this error before using the Ultralytics module, I just changed the imgsz argument and that fixed it.
It appears that torch doesnt support that argument and Im unsure of how to go about fixing this.
Ive tried:

- imgsz
- imgsize
- size
- img_size

And nothing works
Ive looked through this page about torch.hub.load() to no avail:
https://docs.ultralytics.com/yolov5/tutorials/pytorch_hub_model_loading/

I am unsure of what to do from here, any help is appreciated.

#### Code

```
import os
import dxcam
import cv2
import torch 
from ultralytics import YOLO
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='best.onnx', _verbose=False)

# Initzialize a DXcam camera
camera = dxcam.create(device_idx=0, output_color="BGR")
left = 0
top = 0
right = 1360
bottom = 768

cv2.namedWindow("test", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("test", 400, 200)
cv2.setWindowProperty("test", cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST, 1)


while True:
    frame = camera.grab(region=(left,top,right,bottom))
    if frame is None: 
        continue
    
    results = model(frame, img_size=640)

    cv2.imshow("test", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

**Note: This only happens with .onnx models**

**This question is almost an exact copy of [this](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/12519) question that I made on Github**